# AngularJS show/refresh Google Maps inside tab

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Been working on this issue for several hours and cant seem to get a workaround ( even though I read tens of pages on this ).
I have a bootstrap tabs system on a page. On the third tab, I have a google maps div. I know that since the tab isnt visible at first, the map div wont render the map correctly and thus it must be refreshed in a way or another when the tab is selected.
At first I tried to refresh the map but could not get it to work, then I decided to try using a NG-IF condition to have angular render the div again but again something is not working...

Ma tabs are this way in the HTML file :

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a show-tab href="#informations" data-toggle="tab">Informations client</a></li>
        <li ng-if="!client.isNew"><a show-tab href="#contacts" data-toggle="tab">Contacts</a></li>
        <li ng-if="!client.isNew"><a show-tab href="#geolocalisation" data-toggle="tab">Géolocalisation</a></li>
        <li ng-if="!client.isNew"><a show-tab href="#locations" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content tab-container">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="informations"></div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="some_other_stuff"></div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="geolocalisation">
             <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' refresh='map.refresh' ng-if="gmap_visible"></ui-gmap-google-map>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a final tab"></div>
     </div>
```

In my page controler, I initialize the gmap_variable to false thus the ui-gmap-google-map div isnt rendered :

```
myApp.controller('ClientsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', 'modalService', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, modalService, uiGmapGoogleMapApi){
     $scope.gmap_visible = false;
}
```

Finally, I'm using a directive for the tabs to prevent navigation when a tab is clicked, and thought I could update the gmap_visible variable inside it :

```
myApp.directive('showTab',
function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(element).tab('show');

                if (attrs.href == '#geolocalisation'){
                    scope.$parent.gmap_visible = true;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to do the trick and my google map div isnt rendered... ( I tried to use scope=false inside the directive but it didnt work either )

Is there a workaround there, or better would it be possible to use something directly in the ng-if such as

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' refresh='map.refresh' ng-if="parentElement.hasClass('active')">
```

which would render useless any further code ?

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get an answer by searching and tweaking...

Left the ng-if out. Instead, in my ShowTab directive, I emitted an event :

```
if (attrs.href == '#geolocalisation'){
     scope.$emit('setGmapVisible', { gmap_visible: true });
} else {
     scope.$emit('setGmapVisible', { gmap_visible: false });
}
```

This sends the 'setGmapVisible' event up to the root scope. In my controller, I intercept this event like this :

```
$scope.$on('setGmapVisible', function (event, args) {    
    $scope.gmap_visible = args.gmap_visible;
    if ($scope.gmap_visible){

  if ($scope.client == '' || $scope.client === null || $scope.client === undefined){
    var Adresse = 'France';
  } else {
    var Adresse = '';
    if ($scope.client.Adresse_1 != '' && $scope.client.Adresse_1 != null && $scope.client.Adresse_1 != 'undefined'){
      Adresse += $scope.client.Adresse_1;
    }
    if ($scope.client.Adresse_2 != '' && $scope.client.Adresse_2 != null && $scope.client.Adresse_2 != 'undefined'){
      Adresse += ' ' + $scope.client.Adresse_2;
    }
    if ($scope.client.CP != '' && $scope.client.CP != null && $scope.client.CP != 'undefined'){
      Adresse += ' ' + $scope.client.CP;
    }
    if ($scope.client.Ville != '' && $scope.client.Ville != null && $scope.client.Ville != 'undefined'){
      Adresse += ' ' + $scope.client.Ville;
    }
    if ($scope.client.Pays != '' && $scope.client.Pays != null && $scope.client.Pays != 'undefined'){
      Adresse += ' ' + $scope.client.Pays;
    }
  }

  Geocode.geocode(Adresse)
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.map = data.map;
      $scope.map.control = {};
      $scope.marker = data.marker;
      // Timeout pour être sur que le div gmap est visible
      $timeout( function(){ 
        $scope.map.control.refresh({latitude: $scope.map.center.latitude, longitude: $scope.map.center.longitude});
      }, 250);
    });


}

}
```

I'm building up an adress Parameter to send to a Geocode factory which sends back a map object that the google maps service will use. Don't forget to add a control object to this map in order to be able to refresh the map.

Last thing, I added a timeout of 250ms because if not, the tab may not yet be visible and thus the map would not be rendered on the refresh.

The geocoding factory and some more advice were found on [Nick Mitchell's amazing tutorial for angular-google-maps](http://nicmitchell.com/2015/01/quickly-use-street-address-with-google-maps-in-angular/)

Answer given on December 23 1995, hope this helps someone because apparently most people are annoyed by this king of problem !